# iOS app submission - what happens with LocalStorage

Tags: ios, local-storage

What happens to data stored in local storage when you release an iOS app update.  Is it wiped completely or will it still all be available?

Comment: As in, in the "Documents" section of the app?

Answer (score 1):

> When a user downloads an application
>   update, iTunes installs the update in
>   a new application directory. It then
>   moves the user’s data files from the
>   old installation over to the new
>   application directory before deleting
>   the old installation. Files in the
>   following directories are guaranteed
>   to be preserved during the update
>   process:
>
> - `<Application_Home>/Documents`
> - `<Application_Home>/Library`
>
> Although
>   files in other user directories may
>   also be moved over, you should not
>   rely on them being present after an
>   update.

You should check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html in the **Performance Tunning** section for more information!

Comment: So what if you had a plist that contained a NSDictionary with elements "dog" and "cat" in the old version.. and the new version had elements "dog","cat",and "duck"? Would it be added on?

Comment: If your plist is included in the app bundle, the old plist (the one that had "dog" and "cat") will be deleted when the old directory is deleted. The new one will be copied when the app installs in the new directory, so as a conclusion, the only plist available after the update process will be the new one (if we are talking about the app bundle).

Comment: But what about the plist that was retained in the "Documents" directory? Will that get updated too?

Comment: No it won't. You should manually replace it. If the plist only has data generated by you, it would be as easy as deleting the old plist and copying the new one from the bundle. Bare in mind that if the user has made some edits on the plist you should manually import the new data because if you delete the old one and copy a new one you will be deleting user's data.